# changing screen after ok button is pressed in dialog box

Tags: java, libgdx

I was trying to show a success message with dialog box to user before changing the screen. And I want it to wait for user to click the ok button or press Enter key and then change the screen. Since I have to put lots of dialog boxes in my program, to avoid duplicates, I tried to have one createDialog method in my MainClass which creates the dialog boxes and it will add it to the stage which I passed to the method. But the thing is I want it to change the screen to the one I passed to it after the ok button was pressed by user but dialog's result function is an inner method which doesn't access the Screen which I passed to the function. So is there any way that I can do this?

```
public class MainClass extends Game {
    .
    .
    .

    public void createDialog(String message, boolean isWarning, Stage stage, Screen screen) {
        Skin skin2Json = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("freezing/skin/freezing-ui.json"));
        Dialog dialog;
        String title = "Success Message";
        if (isWarning) title = "Error";

        dialog = new Dialog(title, skin2Json, "dialog"){
            @Override
            protected void result(Object object) {
                if((Boolean) object)
                    //if it is a success message ,I want to set screen to the screen passed to the createDialog function
            }
        };
        dialog.getBackground().setMinWidth(400);
        dialog.getBackground().setMinHeight(200);
        dialog.text(message);
        dialog.button("Ok", true);
        dialog.key(Input.Keys.ENTER, true);
        dialog.show(stage);
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways you could do that I guess, but mine would be :

- to use a variable in your class, in the render function, that triggers the change of screen
- to set that variable once you hit the OK in the dialog box.

That would give something like :

```
public class MainClass extends Game {
    private Boolean ChangeScreen = false;
    
    public void render () {
            // This is your typical render function
            if(ChangeScreen) Game.setscreen(new MyOtherScreen());
    }


    public void createDialog(String message, boolean isWarning, Stage stage, Screen screen) {
        Skin skin2Json = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("freezing/skin/freezing-ui.json"));
        Dialog dialog;
        String title = "Success Message";
        if (isWarning) title = "Error";

        dialog = new Dialog(title, skin2Json, "dialog"){
            @Override
            protected void result(Object object) {
                if((Boolean) object)
                    // The OK button has been hit
                    ChangeScreen = true;
            }
        };
        dialog.getBackground().setMinWidth(400);
        dialog.getBackground().setMinHeight(200);
        dialog.text(message);
        dialog.button("Ok", true);
        dialog.key(Input.Keys.ENTER, true);
        dialog.show(stage);
    }
}
```

Maybe not the most elegant way but it should do the trick.

Comment: Hmm. It doesn't completely do what I want it to (changing screen to the screen that I want it to be changed to), but I got the idea that I will write it later. Thanks for answering.